# How to use tuples as inputs to a function in PineScript?

Tags: pine-script

For readability, I have been trying to send tuples as input to functions in pinescript. But I haven't found a way to make it work.

This is the basic idea of what I would like to accomplish:

```
aFunction(xy1,xy2) => 
    [x1,y1]=xy1
    [x2,y2]=xy2
    x = some equation
    y = another equation
    [x,y]
```

With the intention of passing tuples as inputs. In some way similar to this (which actually breaks the preprocessor if attempted):

```
C1 = [a,b]
C2 = [c,d]

w = aFunction(C1,C2)
```

With some tweaks, I can get the initial preprocessing to go through ok, but after a long time I get a "compile" time error that the type of parameters of xy1 and xy2 cannot be determined.

I don't seem to find a 'tuple' type cast or even a tuple parameter type as their support is rather limited.

- Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do?
- Is there even a way to group input parameters so as to highlight the intended meaning, or am I stuck with long lists of indistinguishable input and output parameters?

---

Note that the security function handles tuples and more complex constructs as inputs, so it is a reasonable expectation to have in the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only return tuples from functions. Tuples can't be assigned to a single variable. The variables that make up a tuple can only be used as inputs individually, ie if you have some function that returns a tuple that you wish to pass to another function, you have to manage them individually.

```
someFunction()=>
     do something
     [_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2]

aFunction(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2)=>
     do something
     [_return_value]

[x1, y1, x2, y2] = someFunction()
  
result = aFunction(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. However the built-in security function allows it, which is quite inconsistent if you ask me.

Comment: Yeah, the security and input functions allow it, so the mechanism is already there. I wonder why we cant

Comment: This is not a Tuple then, only a syntax helper to write readable code. Even Arrays are single variables while having N elements. Sometimes I wish Tradingview used a real programming language to dumb-down into a trading language...